Fixing issues with my reading settings file synchronously before any page gets loaded
The following code has the class that I use to store and retrieve data from the device's DocumentsDirectory. The asynchronous versions of retrieving and writing files have been tested to work well.
Because I need to read the settings.json file before the first screen is displayed, so that the settings can be applied to it as well, I am looking for a synchronous method of reading the file. Also, when a setting (thus setting variable) is changed, I write all the variable coded in JSON to the settings.json file, which again I want to be synchronous, so that changes can be saved before another setting change is made.
Although my settings set is not very large, I am looking to use a synchronous method to read to be sure the settings are read before any page loads.
In the following code, readSettingsFileSynchronously() is a modification of the readSettingsFile() function in my attempt to read synchronously (and the function might be incomplete or ill-logically implemented, and I need to fix it if needed). The only change I've made so far is final contents = file.readAsStringSync(); where I've removed await and changed from readAsString() to readAsStringSync(). I am not sure if this is all I needed to do, and if this will work every time as intended. I am also wondering if I have to set the return type of readSettingsFileSynchronously() to String instead of Future<String>, or should I have to leave this as Future<String> because my function body makes use of await. And I tried removing async from the function declaration and also removed await for the getter function _localSettingsFile and declared the return type as String simply but I got error as stated in UPDATE 01.
So, my question is, given the things I have tried above, and code shown below, how can I read the settings file synchronously before the page loads by fixing my code? Please provide enough explanation in your answers.
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class SettingsStorage {
  final String settingsVariablesStorageFileName = "settings.json";

  Future<String> get _localDocumentsDirectoryPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localSettingsFile async {
    final path = await _localDocumentsDirectoryPath;
    return File("$path/$settingsVariablesStorageFileName");
  }

  Future<String> readSettingsFile() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localSettingsFile;

      // Read the file
      final contents = await file.readAsString();

      return contents;
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return 0
      return "Encountered some error; returing default value.";
    }
  }

  // Since, settings file must be read completely before we can apply the
  // settings variables, we read it synchronously rather than asynchronously.
  Future<String> readSettingsFileSynchronously() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localSettingsFile;

      // Read the file synchronously:
      final contents = file.readAsStringSync();

      return contents;
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return 0
      return "Encountered some error; returing default value.";
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeSettingsFile(String text) async {
    final file = await _localSettingsFile;

    // Write the file
    // return file.writeAsString('$text');
    return file.writeAsString(text);
  }
}

UPDATE 01:
Doing as stated in question (01) leads to an error in the line:
final contents = file.readAsStringSync();
saying "The method 'readAsStringSync' isn't defined for the type 'Future'."

@pskink, finished reading partially. Having problem understanding the order of execution! Didn't finish the exercise. Will read error handling tomorrow perhaps. Thanks for the link.

Find your void main() method, change it to Future<void> main() async, add first line here WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();, execute all async/await code that you want before calling runApp.
